# One to many ansible validation of firewall ports

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have this input.csv

```
Server, Check-Server, Firewall-Port,
Server1,Server2,80,
,Server2,9999,
,server8,8443,
Server2,,,
server3,Server6,8443,
,Server9,8888,
```

and I will create a server.yml,

```
---

  Server1:
     name: Server2
        - 80
        - 9999
     name: server8
        - 8443
  Server2:
  server3:
     name: Server6
        - 8443
     name: Server9
        - 8888
```

I have ansible below created but I don't know how to filter this to test the server to another server ports.  This check to all server.

```
--- 
- name: Include file
  include_vars: server.yml


- name: Check if remote host port
  wait_for: host={{ item.name }} port={{ item.port }} timeout=1
  ignore_errors: True
  register: out
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"

- debug: var=out  

- name: Save remote port   
  shell: printf "\n,{{ item.item.name }} port {{ item.item.port }} is {% if item.failed %}closed{% else %}open{% endif %}"  >> /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ out.results }}"

- name: delete local /tmp/fetched
  shell: rm -fr /tmp/fetched/ 
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    warn: False
  ignore_errors: True
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Fetching file
  fetch:
    src: /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv
    dest: /tmp/fetched

- name: Run once on localhost
  shell: echo 'Hostname,IP,CPU-Core,Ram-GB,Disk-GB' > /tmp/fetched/main_output.csv 
  run_once: True
  delegate_to: localhost    

- name: Combined to one file
  shell: cat /tmp/fetched/{{ ansible_hostname }}/tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv >> /tmp/fetched/main_output.csv && printf '\r\n' >> /tmp/fetched/main_output.csv
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The servers.yml should be like this,

---

servers:
  - server1: centos
    server2: vm1
    port: 22
  - server1: centos
    server2: vm2
    port: 22
  - server1: vm2
    server2: vm1
    port: 22
  - server1: vm1
    server2: vm2
    port: 80

The ansible script should be like this,

---

- name: Include server firewall to check
  include_vars: server.yml
- name: Get hostname
  shell: echo {{ ansible_hostname }}  > /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_data.csv

  ## no_log: true

  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Get IP
  shell: hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1 >> /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_data.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Get cpu core
  shell: nproc >> /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_data.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Get memory ***memory-caluculation***
  shell: awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo > memory
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Get memory in GB ***memory-caluculation***
  shell: awk '{ print $1/1000000}' memory >> /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_data.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Get Disk Info ***disk-calculation***

  ## calculation will be wrong if there's a disk with MB

  ## and /dev/vd is used instead of /dev/sd

  shell: fdisk -l|grep /dev/sd > disk && awk '/Disk /dev/sd/ {print $3}' disk  > disk2
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Get how many disk ***disk-calculation***
  shell: cat disk2 | wc -l
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
  register: countline
- name: Calculate the sum of disks ***disk-calculation***
  shell: awk '{sum+=$1} (NR%{{countline.stdout}})==0{print sum}' disk2 >> /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_data.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: delete csv
  shell: rm -f /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
  warn: false
  ignore_errors: True
- name: Put it in CSV in one line
  shell: cat /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_data.csv | awk '{print}' ORS=','  > /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
- name: Check if remote host port
  wait_for: host={{ item.server2 }} port={{ item.port }} timeout=1
  ignore_errors: True
  register: out
  when: item.server1 == ansible_hostname
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
- debug: var=out
- name: Save remote port
  shell: printf "\n,{{ item.item.server2 }} port {{ item.item.port }} is {% if item.failed %}closed{% else %}open{% endif %}"  >> /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
  when: item.item.server1 == ansible_hostname
  with_items: "{{ out.results }}"
- name: delete local /tmp/fetched
  shell: rm -fr /tmp/fetched/ 
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
  warn: False
  ignore_errors: True
  delegate_to: localhost
- name: Fetching file
  fetch:
  src: /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv
  dest: /tmp/fetched
- name: Run once on localhost
  shell: echo 'Hostname,IP,CPU-Core,Ram-GB,Disk-GB' > /tmp/fetched/main_output.csv 
  run_once: True
  delegate_to: localhost
- name: Combined to one file
  shell: cat /tmp/fetched/{{ ansible_hostname }}/tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_output.csv >> /tmp/fetched/main_output.csv && printf '\r\n' >> /tmp/fetched/main_output.csv
  args:
  executable: /bin/bash
  delegate_to: localhost

  And the output.csv should be like this,

Hostname,IP,CPU-Core,Ram-GB,Disk-GB
vm1,192.168.2.70,1,0.999696,21.5,
,vm2 port 80 is open
centos,192.168.2.100,2,1.86599,85.9,
,vm1 port 22 is open
,vm2 port 22 is open
vm2,192.168.2.71,2,1.86705,86,
,vm1 port 22 is open